# How to retain textbox values after navigating to other page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page(say register page) with text boxes in it. After entering values in them, if I navigate to other to page by using back and forward buttons in the browser and come back to the register page again. I want the entered text box values to be shown. Is there any way to do that. Hope somebody could help. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Cookies, local storage or serverside variables comes to mind, you pick one that fits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to retain value of the variable after the page is reloaded/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879985/how-to-retain-value-of-the-variable-after-the-page-is-reloaded)

Comment: May be you need to cache or session variable for each controls, and load value from them if present .similarly save the current value to respective `cache /session variable` before submitting the form

Comment: If the page is loaded from the cache(which is by default) the data that has been typed in those textboxes will retain untill and unless the source code forces the form page to be reloaded from the server. So I think this is not at all a problem.

Comment: Everyone Thanks for help. Just used this code.


<script type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
window.content.localStorage['name']=document.getElementById('name').value;
        return null; 
    }
function loadfun()
{
document.getElementById('name').value=window.content.localStorage['name'];
delete window.content.localStorage['name'];
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadfun()">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saving to local storage is a bit dangerous, because anyone can go to console and type:
window.localStorage to see the saved values, for  ALL USERS of the domain.

for example, on this page of SO right now, the localstorage contains this :

```
Storage {login-prefs: "{"provider":"google","oauth_version":"","oauth_server":"","username":""}",     se:fkey: "c6f10e10979159fee3220954ec846d68,1387300621", wb:isparticipating: "{"1106914":{"t":1387805621703,"v":false}}"}
```

assuming that the textbox values do not contain personal information,
you will still need to address issue of multiple users on same machine.

one solution will be to use the user ID as a key, the value as a json representation of textboxId : value

example:

on window.befreunload event, strore all the textbox values under a key containing user ID:

localStorage.setItem( 'user_123_form-values' , JSON.stringify( [{ txbox1: 'some text'   }, { txbox2: 'some other text'   }])  );

to get values:

JSON.parse(localStorage['user_123_form-values'])

here is a fiddle to demonstrate the local storage approach, though if the data needs to be secure,
you will need to use cookies:

http://jsfiddle.net/LLyB6/2/

Answer (score 0):

JS variables never have been persistent, but there are two ways around this:

1.Cookies
2.Storage
Cookies are supported in all but the most ancient browsers, but they can be very unwieldly and difficult to use. On top of that, your browser sends cookies to the server with every pageload, so if it's only used by JavaScript then it's very inefficient.

Instead, you should probably look at the Storage option.

Saving an item is as simple as `localStorage.itemname = value`; Reading is as easy as `localStorage.itemname`, and deleting is as literal as `delete localStorage.itemname`

These values are saved across pageloads, but not sent to the server.

from:

[Javascript global variable does not persist when navigate to another page (which also uses same js file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139351/javascript-global-variable-does-not-persist-when-navigate-to-another-page-which)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is done using session / cookie / Appending query string:

Check this answer: [PHP Pass variable to next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page)